# Make script Error on "Authenticity of host cannot be established" message

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am writing a wrapper script that sets up passwordless ssh to other servers for other scripts to then use.

The issue is that the inner scripts are not capable of taking user input. For example, whenever it receives

> The authenticity of host 'hostname.server (XXX.XXX.XX.XX)' can't be  established.
>
> RSA key fingerprint is RS:A-:FI:NG:ER:PR:IN:T-.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

and a user enters anything (no, yes or nothing and press enter), the inner scripts fail because they were not expecting input. *I do not have any control over the inner scripts, nor can I edit them.*

My wrapper script essentially sets up ssh, and also tests ssh into the server before the other scripts run.

**I want the wrapper script to error on any ssh response that requires user input (like aforementioned one above) as well as any kind of ssh error, so the failure is known sooner in the wrapper script rather than later in the inner scripts.**

**What is a good way to do this?**

Comment: How about starting with `ssh -o BatchMode=yes` ?

Comment: This is essentially what I was looking for. Supply this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSH option you're looking for is `BatchMode`.

From the man page:

```
 BatchMode
         If set to ``yes'', passphrase/password querying will be disabled.
         This option is useful in scripts and other batch jobs where no
         user is present to supply the password.  The argument must be
         ``yes'' or ``no''.  The default is ``no''.
```

It might also be valuable to set a timeout for your connections, so that network problems don't cause your ssh client to hang around forever:

```
 ConnectTimeout
         Specifies the timeout (in seconds) used when connecting to the
         SSH server, instead of using the default system TCP timeout.
         This value is used only when the target is down or really
         unreachable, not when it refuses the connection.
```

The default value for ConnectTimeout may be 0, which would cause ssh to wait forever.

You can put this on the command line:

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=15 me@host.example.com
```

or in a configuration file like `~/.ssh/config`:

```
host example host.example.com
    hostname host.example.com
    user me
    BatchMode yes
    ConnectTimeout 15
```

Note that upon failing to connect, SSH will return a status in its exit value, so you might use shell constructs like:

```
if ! ssh example bin/do_something; then
  echo "ERROR: bailing out of $0." >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

The ssh command will also produce standard error explaining why it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Add the host fingerprint to the known_hosts file before calling ssh

```
ssh-keyscan -H your_hostname >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Just make sure you trust the server before adding the fingerprint to the known_hosts to avoid security issues.

Comment: I was doing this already, and still getting "The authenticity can't be established." messages. The problem was that I was dealing with host names that had duplicate IP addresses (we are manufacturing boxes, and can have infinite hostnames but not infinite IPs, we have to recycle IPs). Because StrictHostKey checking was set to "ask" and not "no" I was still getting "The authenticity can't be established." messages and because the known hosts is made of the hostname AND IP address.

Comment: Should be ok provided that hostname/IP pairs does not change. The problem will appear when you assign a different IP to an already present hostname.